# Show Hide Div's Dependant on Click

Tags: javascript, onclick, hide, show

I am trying to code a "page" which asks user a question with a yes/no answer. If they answer "yes" a new "page" will be shown if they answer "no" a different "page" will be shown. In total there will be 6 different "pages".

I will load all "pages" in a div's and hide all but the first one.

I'm not really sure where to start with JS Code, should I code show/hide for each page separetely or can I combine in a single case 0: case 1 type function ?

```css
.page { display:none; width:100%; }
#p1 {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div id="lpage"> 


<section class="page" id="p1">
<h1>This is Page 1</h1>
<div class="yes">Yes</div>
<div class="no">No</div>
</section>

<section class="page" id="p2">
<h1>This is Page 2</h1>
<div class="yes">Yes</div>
<div class="no">No</div>
</section>

<section class="page" id="p3">
<h1>This is Page 3</h1>
<div class="yes">Yes</div>
<div class="no">No</div>
</section>

<section class="page" id="p4">
<h1>This is Page4</h1>
<div class="yes">Yes</div>
<div class="no">No</div>
</section>

<section class="page" id="p5">
<h1>This is Page 5</h1>
<div class="yes">Yes</div>
<div class="no">No</div>
</section>

<section class="page" id="p6">
<h1>This is Page 6</h1>
<div class="yes">Yes</div>
<div class="no">No</div>
</section>

</div>
```

Comment: Are the pages different files, or are they different divs? I would actually suggest having one page in which you have different panels. You can dynamically change the z-index attribute of each panel based on the user's choice determined by the buttons. You can make the panels take up the entire width and height of the page by using this css: `.mypanel{position:absolute;(or fixed) top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;}`

Comment: I hope I understand your question. I'm not quite sure if I have it right.

Comment: Just to clarify - the "pages" are different divs on the same page

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery (what I recommend), you can make a simple function for this functionality:

```
function showPage(id) {
$('section.page').hide();
$('#p'+id).show();
}

//show page 3
showPage(3);
```

Comment: Sorry, got confused by this code - not really sure what its doing

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using JQuery:

```
$(".yes").click(function() {
  var parentSectionId = $(this).parent(".page").attr('id');

  if(parentSectionID == "p1") {
     $("#p2").hide();
     $("#p4").hide();
     $("#p3").show();
  }

  if(parentSectionID = "p2") {
     ...
  }
```

and so on.  Then you handle the no cases in a separate click function, just replacing yes with no.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I can see how this code works - however I think i did something wrong because it doesn't appear to be working - have set it up here http://jsfiddle.net/czk8ja22/